# How do I get all iframe elements?

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe

I'm showing a loading indicator while some external iframes are loaded with the following code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Loading iframe</title>
    </head>

    <script>


    function loading_iframe(){
        document.getElementById('loading_iframe').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "";
        document.getElementById('loading_iframe').onload = function(){
            document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('loading_iframe').style.display = "";
        }
    }
    </script>

    <body>
        <iframe id="loading_iframe" src="iframe.html" width="800" height="100"></iframe>
        <div id="loading">Loading...</div>


        <script>
            loading_iframe();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem is I'm running around 50 mini iframes per page and I don't fancy rewriting the code above to match each iframe id.

Is there a way I could match each iframe id with a regex, for example:

- loading_iframe1
- loading_iframe2
- loading_iframe3

Comment: Added it to my answer, but you shouldn't be putting `<script>` tags between the `head` and `body`..... they should either be in the `head` with a doc ready or after the needed `html` in the body.... usually right before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using plain vanilla JavaScript: Assuming the `loading_iframe` function performs the exact same action for every iframe, what you can do is have an array that contains the IDs of all iframes, then loop through that array.

```
function load_iframes() {
    iframes = ["loading_iframe1", "loading_iframe2", "loading_iframe3"];
    for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        loading_iframe(iframes[i]);
    }
}

function loading_iframe(iframe_id){
    document.getElementById(iframe_id).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById(iframe_id).onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(iframe_id).style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this version of `load_iframes` will work if you're going to have a sequential number in your iframe IDs starting at 1 and ending at 50, and you don't need to list all your iframe IDs in an array:

```
function load_iframes() {
    num_iframes = 50;
    for (i = 1; i <= num_iframes; i++) {
        loading_iframe("loading_iframe" + i);
    }
}
```

Using jQuery: Give all iframes a CSS class such as `loading_iframe`.  You can then use jQuery to select all elements that have the `loading_iframe` class.

Answer (score 20):

First, `<script>` tags should go either in the `<head>` or the `<body>` but not in between!

---

I would change your naming scheme slightly to this:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="iframe.html" width="800" height="100"></iframe>
<div id="iframe1-L">Loading...</div>

<iframe id="iframe2" src="blah.html" width="800" height="100"></iframe>
<div id="iframe2-L">Loading...</div>
```

Now you just have to loop through all the iframes, and you can easily access the corresponding div by changing the ID to `+"-L"`

To get all the `iframe` elements use **[getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)**, then iterate over those with a for loop:

Something like this:

```
var i, frames;
frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i)
{
      // The iFrame
    frames[i].style.display = "none";
      // The corresponding DIV
    getElementById(frames[i].id + "-L").style.display = "";
    frames[i].onload = function()
    {
        getElementById(frames[i].id + "-L").style.display = "none";
        frames[i].style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Jeff's answer: I really recommend you to check out jQuery. It is very powerful and a task like this should be fairly simple. Given that you give each iFrame a class "loading_iframe" you can do something like:

```
$(".loading_iframe").each(function(index) {
   console.log(this); ;
});
```

The console.log() call assumes that you use FireBug in Firefox or Google Chrome. Not sure if that works in other browsers.

Also see the [document for .each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing magical about jQuery, you can do this without it as well: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("loading_frame"), function(frame) { console.log(frame); })`. A bit more verbose but you can refactor it into your common use case and you don't need to load jQuery.