# How to iterate all the iframes in the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i iterate all the iframes(tag) which includes child iframes(tag) inside the window/document on page loads.Content can be cross origin or same origin.

Comment: can you please share the html

Comment: You can't inspect cross-origin iframe documents in your script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all iframe elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774015/get-all-iframe-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
$('body > iframe').each(function() {
    // do something for parent iframe
    $(this).children('iframe').each(function() {
       // do something for children iframes
    });
});
```